# Dell Inspiron 7720 won't boot from USB

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, dell-inspiron

I bricked my machine trying to reinstall the OS and so I got the Windows ISO install from MSDN, put it on a USB stick. But the computer won't boot from the stick either. I've followed numerous tutorials to verify that the stick is correctly created, and that the BIOS is set to boot from the stick, but the BIOS says `Operation [sic] system not found`.

I'm running the latest version of the BIOS for this machine (A16) and I'm pulling my hair out because my primary work computer is dead and I really don't want to buy a whole new machine because of something that's probably small and stupid.

Comment: How did you create the USB drive?  Just extracting the ISO won't make it bootable.  You'll need to use YUMI or something similar to do so.

Comment: I used dd (on a mac) to write directly to the stick: `sudo dd if=/en_windows_8.1_enterprise_with_update_x64_dvd_4065178.iso of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m`